# constraints not working programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, constants

```
func textFields() {
    let nameField = MDCFilledTextField()
    view.addSubview(nameField)
    nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nameField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        nameField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        nameField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        nameField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
    nameField.placeholder = "Name"
}
```

I am using google material design and create a textfield.For this purpose and i have used this code i want to space from both sides left and right but it works only one side left or right i want to space from both side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the `MDCFilledTextField` position in a wrong way. The following line tells your view to use a static predefined frame size:

```
let estimatedFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-20, height: 50)
let nameField = MDCFilledTextField(frame: estimatedFrame)
```

But further down with the following rows you tell your view to use autolayout:

```
nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    nameField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    nameField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    nameField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    nameField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
])
```

So now you have to decide which one would you like to use, the static frame or the autolayout. If you decide to go with the autolayout you have to improve your code in order to remove the error you get. First you need to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true instead of false.

```
nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

This line will tell that you want to use the autolayout for `nameField` instead of a static frame. Further you need to add your view to the superview first, otherwise you can't define your constraints(therefore the error you have). So your code becomes:

```
func textFields() {
    let nameField = MDCFilledTextField()
    view.addSubview(nameField)
    nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nameField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        nameField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        nameField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        nameField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
    nameField.placeholder = "Name"
}
```

Comment: Just tested the code and it seems to work on my device.

Comment: I have used it's working on top and left as like frame but it doesn't work constant from right

Comment: try: `CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-20, height: 50)`

Comment: I have used also this it's also same work

Comment: If you use frame this line show work. The trick is here `UIScreen.main.bounds.width-20` as you define your `x: 10` therefore the view width is not the screen width but 10 less on the left and if we want to make it look nice than 10 on the right side. therefore the -20

Comment: I want to space 10 from both sides left and right your 1st example give left space width-20 display space from right only

Comment: Please double check it, I am pretty sure it will give you 10 padding on both sides if you use: `CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-20, height: 50)`

Comment: It's displaying only one side padding

Comment: Double check that you do not override the frame somewhere else, and not to use autolayout instead of frame. The solution is correct, I double checked.

Comment: I also double checked

Comment: Try to update your question, and post what you are trying

Comment: I updated my answer: It is possible to use a) centerXAnchor and widthAnchor + multiplier or b) leftAnchor and rightAnchor + constants.

Answer (score 0):

Add the nameField as a subview of the view before activating the constraint and remove of using frames.

To add padding use for example centerXAnchor and widthAnchor + multiplier

```
func textFields() {
        
        let nameField = MDCFilledTextField()
        nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(nameField)
                
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            nameField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            nameField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            nameField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9)
        ])
       
        nameField.placeholder = "Name"
        nameField.label.text = "Name"
        nameField.setFloatingLabelColor(.lightGray, for: MDCTextControlState.editing)
}
```

or add constants to the leftAnchor and rightAnchor.

```
func textFields() {
        
        let nameField = MDCFilledTextField()
        nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(nameField)
                
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            nameField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            nameField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
            nameField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
      
        nameField.placeholder = "Name"
        nameField.label.text = "Name"
        nameField.setFloatingLabelColor(.lightGray, for: MDCTextControlState.editing)
}
```

Comment: It's working only top and left but doesn't constant from right

Comment: @Hammad2: I updated my answer. You can use a) centerXAnchor and widthAnchor + multiplier or b) leftAnchor and rightAnchor + constants.